# BOOT_COMPLETED Receiver doesn't fire if the device isn't in use soon after starting

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

OK, I test my android apps on two phones. A Samsung galaxy s6, and an s4. Android version 7 on the former and 5 on the latter.

The problem I'm having seems to be exclusive to the galaxy s4 running android version 5. My apps need to run some code after the system boots, so obviously they have a boot_completed receiver. It runs fine on my galaxy s6, but on the s4, if the screen is off after boot up, the boot completed receiver doesn't run. If I'm using the phone soon after it boots it's fine, but if I boot it and just leave the phone with the screen off for a while before use, the receiver isn't run. So basically it seems like if the phone is asleep it doesn't run the boot completed receiver when it should. It's not simply being delayed till I run the screen back on, it never gets fired.

I haven't had much luck finding examples of this problem and how to fix it with Google. I've been a coder for a very long time but I'm fairly inexperienced with android. So if anyone knows what the problem is or ideas on how it might best be fixed it would be greatly appreciated.

The boot completed receiver runs fine if I'm using the phone for the first few minutes after it boots, but if I'm not, it never fires. It seems to be missed completely. It doesn't run when I start using the phone again if I wasn't in the few minutes after boot. It ends up never getting run at all.  It only works properly if I'm using the phone in the few minutes after it first boots. Otherwise, it never runs.

I know there are features for running code on boot in Android 7 with a locked screen on boot, locked_boot_completed or something. But strangely I'm not encountering a problem on my android 7 device, and it's my understanding that this feature isn't available for Android 5 where I'm encountering this problem. And if it's simply the case that it won't broadcast boot_completed with a locked screen in earlier versions of Android, I'm wondering if anyone knows a way around the problem.

Comment: How did you define the receiver tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I have two apps I'm experiencing this issue with. One uses its receiver to start a service which listens on a UDP port, the other just sets up some repeating alarms

The receiver tag for the two manifests are identical...

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>             

Both have the receive boot completed permission, making sure the app is run once doesn't help.

Comment: How do you know the receiver isn't being triggered? Are you looking for the alarms or `Service` you mentioned, or are you living something in `onReceive`? Power management comes into play with regards to broadcast receivers and it is possible for your receiver to fire, but after it's `onReceive` exits the system goes to low power and your other components will not run immediately.

Comment: One of the apps I can set to send a notification when the boot receiver is triggered. That notification never shows up if the phone is locked for the first 15 minutes or so after boot. My galaxy s6 seems to have no problem but the s4 doesn't seem to run the receiver in those conditions. The other app starts a service that listens for UDP packets. It's essentially a type of find my phone utility. So it should set off an alert if it receives the trigger packet. Provided the phone was unlocked for the first little while after booting it works fine. Even if left locked indefinitely after.

Comment: Both apps boot receivers fail, either by not sending the boot receiver notification and not scheduling the alarms or for the other app by not responding to the udp packet sent over the LAN, if the phone was locked for the first 15 minutes or so after booting. Since they function correctly on one of the phones, and only appear to malfunction on the other if the phone was locked around the time the boot receiver should might have fired, the only explanation I can think of is that the galaxy s4 on Android 5 isn't firing the receiver if it's locked for a while after boot.